# How to add double quotations only to the first word of each line in the text file using shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting

I have text file like this:

```
"(he|' ni a k k)"

"(she|' ni b h k)"

"(run|' ni a k k)"
```

but i need text file like the following:

```
("he|'" ni a k k)

("she|'" ni b h k)

("run|'" ni a k k)
```

How to add double quotations only to the first word of each line in the text file using shell script?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/"//g' -e "s/'/'\"/" -e 's/(/("/' input.txt
```